# Dump Symfony2 assets to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, symfony, assets

I'd like to dump my assets to my s3 bucket in production, after deploying with capifony in Symfony 2. I've found some solution, but don't really find out the best to use.

It's possible the dump the assets with Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 but I think it's a bit overkill to import the Zend framework only for this. - http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.symfony.symfony2/54

I've also found this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/108, where I can tell AsseticBundle the bucket name, but I didn't found where to provide the key and secret for my aws account.

Can you point out a better solution, or give me some detailed information on the above mentioned ones.

Answer (score 6):

So what I've done and it is working.

Add at `composer.json` and install it

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.6.16",
```

Create a service:

```
<?php

namespace My\AcmeBundle\Amazon;

use Aws\Common\Aws;

class StreamWrapperS3 {

    protected $s3;

    public function __construct($key, $secret, $region) {

        $aws = array(
            'key'    => $key,
            'secret' => $secret,
            'region' => $region
        );

        $this->s3 = Aws::factory($aws)->get('s3');

    }

    public function registerStreamWrapper() {
        $this->s3->registerStreamWrapper();
    }

}
```

Declare the service at`config.yml` or including it as a file

```
services:
    my_amazon_s3:
        class: My\AcmeBundle\Amazon\StreamWrapperS3
        arguments: [%aws_key%, %aws_secret_key%, %aws_region%]
```

Add the parameters at `parameters.yml`

Override `boot()` method at `AppKernel.php`:

```
public function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    $s3client = $this->container->get('my_amazon_s3');;
    $s3client->registerStreamWrapper();
}
```

At `config_prod.yml` add:

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_url: https://sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name
assetic:
    write_to: 's3://your-bucket-name'
```

Finally add the filter with your assets to rewrite correctly your paths:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    'bundles/...' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" /> {# asset just to be sure that url will be right #}
{% endstylesheets %}
```

So each time that you've changed something need to run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console assets:install --env=prod
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

A very important detail that took almost 2 days of my time, you need to update CORS of Amazon S3 to access some files as fonts add inside twitter bootstrap css for example. My CORS permissions are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: didn't work well if we have rewrite url rule and the the css contains image to relative url as the image is not uploaded to S3

Comment: don't do `asset(asset_url)` for assetic or we will get assets version twice `assets.css?version008?version008`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't really need and probably even shouldn't, put your key in the application code. In Amazon S3 you can specify access by sender, in this case you're production server address.

Take a look at the provided post link:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=236066

This would allow you to freely write from that server to your bucket. Remember also to deny access from every other ip.

Answer (score 1):

> I've also found this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/108,
>   where I can tell AsseticBundle the bucket name, but I didn't found
>   where to provide the key and secret for my aws account.

This should work - just use the following form when specifying the S3 bucket URL:

```
# config_prod.yml
assetic:
    write_to: s3://{key}:{secret}@{bucket}/
```

Comment: What else should I add in config_prod? When I run: `php app/console assetic:dump s3://my-cucket --env=prod` it returns `PHP Warning:  is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "s3" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

Comment: @Cassiano I encounter the same issue. Have you solve it?