# Symfony2 - Gregwar/Image Bundle - resized images cache to S3 (Cloudfront)

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to use the Amazon Cloudfront service as a CDN.
My question is: 
How can get Gregwar/ImageBundle to work with S3?

So this:

```
{% set img_path = asset('assets/' ~ app.request.get('product_id') ~ '/images/' ~ contents.background) %}
<img src="{{ web_image(img_path).forceResize(1000) }}" alt="{{contents.title|default('') }}">
```

generates this:

```
https://s3-cdn.com/cache/f/5/f/1/4/f5f1407eb85e38e94019a03082b10611f57b22e5.png
```

instead of this:
`/cache/f/5/f/1/4/f5f1407eb85e38e94019a03082b10611f57b22e5.png` (local fylesystem)

Some update:
I could figure out the asset dumping with this:
[Dump Symfony2 assets to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163717/dump-symfony2-assets-to-amazon-s3)
I can not set the permission to readable for the public.
I have written a stream wrapper for S3 (protocol) in Symfony.

Also it seems that the Gregwar/ImagineBundle does not support CDN...
As you track down the upload folder config, you can see... tell me if i wrong...

Other thing:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4014

> Closing as generating the cache directly on S3 won't be supported as
>   there are many other ways to move files from the computer where you
>   generated your cache to S3.

*by fabpot*

Anyway it is sorted out as I can use the assetic:install in symfony command line, just could not figure out setting the public access for the uploaded/generated assets with S3 streamwrapper...

Problems remaining:

- symfony assetic install/dump to S3 with the right settings so
  available for the public
- Gregwar/ImageBundle -> generated images (ie.: forceResize(), usually to /web/cache/...) to CDN

Another update:

- symfony assetic install/dump -> I decided to use Bower and Grunt to get the same result. Still no idea how to add that public amazon ACL thingie for the command line... sorry, add a comment here if you know
- image uploads -> I am on to "extend" the symfony UploadedFile so when that is triggered to move the file, than the official AWS SDK S3 take over the process and handles it... will let you know with the solution.... [update] I could not modify the move method in a "standard" or non-hacking way. So I created a helper class (using the SDK) and did refactoring with it on the right places.
- the Gregwar/ImageBundle cache (after processing images based upon the Twig "function" you know .forceResize) still outstanding... any thoughts are welcome

Cheers
Greg

Comment: you want the link to be https://s3-cdn.com/cache/f/5/f/1/4/f5f1407eb85e38e94019a03082b10611f57b22e5.png
 or /cache/f/5/f/1/4/f5f1407eb85e38e94019a03082b10611f57b22e5.png? its a bit ambiguous

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. I want this: https://s3-cdn.com/cache/f/5/f/1/4/f5f1407eb85e38e94019a03082b10611f57b22e5.png

Comment: As you may note below, the question you've asked does not seem to convey the *actual* question you want to have answered. Please consider revising it. Also, S3 is not actually a CDN.  CloudFront is the AWS CDN product, and is arguably simpler to integrate into a working application, because CloudFront fetches the object from your server.  S3 is an object store with static asset web serving capabilities, and you have to actively submit each asset to S3.

Answer (score 0):

If https://s3-cdn.com will not change you can concatenate it for your src like this :

```
 src="https://s3-cdn.com~{{ web_image(img_path).forceResize(1000) }}"
```

or make a twig extension to be cleaner or override the web_image function to build correctly your url and return the right one, overriding it would result on the bundle working only for S3.

## update

This question is ambiguous, he wants to upload to S3 not read from it, the twig have nothing to do here.

for more information on the upload :

github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/master/Resources/… this is a nice bundle it uses the league/flysystem take a look at the page see how they handle uploads to amazon flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/aws-s3-v3

Comment: Thanks for the response! I want the image created by Gregwar/ImageBundle forced to be uploaded to S3 to its right place.

Comment: Then that have nothing to do with the twig you are showing, you need controller to connect to s3 then create the url with gregwar from controller  to upload. This have nothing to do with twig lookup the bundle league/flysystem i think they have S3 support out of the box

Comment: Thanks Nawfal! You are right. I am searching for that kind of solution. Not found yet.  I could find a way with LiipImagine and KnpGraufette Bundle to handle S3, but not with Gregwar/Image.

Comment: https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/adapter_awss3.md  this is a nice bundle it uses the league/flysystem  take a look at the page see how they handle uploads to amazon http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/aws-s3-v3/

Comment: if the answer helped you can accept it for others to find it.

Comment: Sorry mate! That is not the right answer for me. I am getting closer to reach the goal. Of course I will update the question or answer to help others.

Comment: I am talking about this line:
`{{ web_image(img_path).forceResize(1000) }}`
cache should goes to S3...
This is the outstanding stuff, the others are done with symfony2... will share a better answer here when i am done... Have a great day!